# How can I delete an object from the Google Cloud Storage using PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Can someone tell me how to delete an object from the Google Cloud Storage using PHP?

I found how to add an object via

```
move_uploaded_file($gs_name, "gs://sample-storage/myfolder/new_file2.jpg");
```

get the public URL via

```
$public_url = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl("gs://sample-storage/myfolder/new_file2.jpg", true);
```

By importing the following as well

```
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
```

But how do you **delete** a file using PHP?

Can someone please share the code in PHP that works? Even using JavaScript if PHP doesn't implicitly support it.

Comment: Any of PHP's file functions should work just fine with the `gs://` scheme paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [delete_object](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/src/delete_object.php) example, you could try adding a function like this to your project:

```
function delete_object($bucketName, $objectName, $options = [])
{
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->object($objectName);
    $object->delete();
    printf('Deleted gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, $bucketName, $objectName);
}
```

Then to delete the actual file, you could use the function like this:

```
delete_object('sample-storage', 'myfolder/new_file2.jpg');
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer...the other answer won't work because it's not in your file system.

Answer (score 4):

You can use unlink (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to do that, e.g.

```
unlink("gs://sample-storage/foo.jpg");
```